# html css sticky, etc

Tags: html, css

For the code below, I have two problems:

1. The background image cereal.jpeg was working, now for some reason, it's disappeared and I can't figure why. Because it used to work, I know the file name and location are correct.
2. My controls refuse to remain sticky!

```css
div.container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 8px black;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 700px;
}

div.container::before {
  background-image: url("cereal.jpeg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: 0.05;
}

div.controls {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: -webkit-sticky; // Safari
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div.thePlots {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container class=container>
  <div class=controls id=controls>
    <label id="brand">Brand:</label>
    <br>
    <select size=7 id="brandOptions" multiple>
      <option value=0 selected>All</option>
      <option value=1>Kellog</option>
      <option value=2>Post</option>
      <option value=3>Quaker</option>
      <option value=4>General Mills</option>
      <option value=5>Tree House</option>
      <option value=6>CPW</option>
    </select>

    <br><br><br>

    <label id="barsLabel">Error Bars:</label>
    <input id=barsPresent type=checkbox value="Error Bars" checked>

    <br><br><br>

    <label id="label">Elasticity<br>Means:</label>
    <br>
    <select id="plotY">
      <option value="efm" selected="selected">efm</option>
      <option value="enm">enm</option>
    </select>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class=thePlots id=thePlots>
    The Plots<br>
    <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>
    <div id="plotshare" class="plotshare"></div>
    <div id="plotprice" class="plotprice"></div>
    <div id="plotsugar" class="plotsugar"></div>
    <div id="plotmushy" class="plotmushy"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want that background? Do you want it to be the background of your container div? Why are you using the before selector?

Comment: Because I want the pic to be very very transparent repeated all across the "container" div. If I don't use it on the before selector, all the contents also become transparent. That's why I put it on the before, then add in all the other contents afterwards.

Comment: your sticky element is inside an element that do not scroll, so it goes up with it .(top:0 here takes #container for reference, not the window ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzRoZg

Comment: you'll need to explain more about your image working and then not working. what did you change?

Comment: ::before needs the content:''; rule to be triggered , then, it would also need to have a size to show some backgrounds .....

Comment: Tough to say Tom, this was part of a much larger piece of code and I extracted the minimum code and it should work, but it doesn't. I just know the file name, the repeat and the opacity haven't changed, the divs changed though.

Comment: @G-Cyr - what's the solution to the sticky problem? Also I don't understand your content comment.

Comment: If you do not set the content rule , the pseudo element is not generated . your code does produce nothing. then an empty pseudo element has no size, so no background to show. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: for the sticky position, it sticks inside the parent and will stick when the parent have a scrollbar untill the parent will move itself. it sticks to its parent . position:fixed do stick to the window, not sticky. I did link a pen to show how it could work ...

Comment: @user1978237 please check my answer. Your comment `// safari` in CSS is causing a problem. That is not how you comment in css

Comment: @user1978237 I added a fiddle which solves both problems

Comment: @G-cyr - I added this, it didn't help - div.container::before {
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div.controls` element is sticking just fine, but it's sticking to the top of your `container` element. If you put it outside out your `container` element you will see it stick to the top of the page as desired.

Also, you will need to remove the `// safari` from your css. The correct syntax for commenting in css is `/* comment */`

For the background issue, there is no content for your background to display behind. You will need to add something to the `before` in order for the background to show.

Check this working fiddle which solves both problems
: https://jsfiddle.net/c5vrhf7t/1/

Comment: I want it to be enclosed inside that shadowed box, so I don't want the controls to be attached to the body and be outside that container. I'm not an html programmer so I may not be thinking about this correctly.

Comment: You mean visually you want it to be enclosed? If so, you can just add a small left and top margin. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5vrhf7t/1/ Unless there is a functional reason you need it to be within that container...

Comment: Whew! That did it! Thanks!! One question though, in the container, why does the the position have to be relative and the container::before the position there is absolute? What's the theory?

Comment: An absolutely positioned element is removed from the flow of the page, and is positioned relative to the document. If you want it to be positioned relative to it's parent container, you need to declare the parent as such. For example, an element with `position:absolute` and `top:50%` will position itself 50% of the page height from the top of the document. But if the element's parent is declared `position:relative`, the element will position itself 50% of the parent element's height from the top of the parent element.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. `opacity` is too low.
2. Remove `float:left;`

Comment: Nope, neither of those make a difference. Its something else.